# Applying of an API on Bar chart to represent data give error swiftUI

Tags: swift, api, user-interface, charts

How can I create 1 chart that represent an array of points rather than creating a multiple charts that represent different value.... What can you recommend to use instead of ForEach...

**Challenge:**

```
ForEach(vm.res) { resul in             
    BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: [("",resul.new_cases)]), title: "")
}
```

Unfortunately I get this outcome.

[image]

However I am required of creating something similar to this:

Requirement:

```
    BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: [

                ("Jan", 12),
                ("Feb", 5),
                ("Mar", 10),
                ("Apr", 7),
                ("May", 6),
                ("Jun", 18),
                ("Jul", 21),
                ("Aug", 1),
                ("Jul", 21),
                ("Aug", 1),

            ]),
                            title: "")
```

[image]

After my API Fetch I want data to be represented on the BarChart, however I can not, I am trying to replace the doubles in the array of values with data from Doubles from an api... However it repeating itself, I believe the problem is with **FOR EACH or ID**

I Have used this Swift Package Manager for reference...

https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView

Comment: Remove the ForEach, and just do `BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: vm.res.map{ ("", $0.new_cases)}), title: "")` or something like that? Ie, the ForEach will create a new "cell", while you want one cell with all the values. So create an array of ChartData values and give it to `BarCharView` instead.

Comment: Man @Larme Thank you so much it worked could you tell me for dynamic change in code shal I use a switch statement ?

Comment: Please Write your answer separately not in comment so I can mark you as a correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing:

```
ForEach(vm.res) { resul in 
    BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: [("",resul.new_cases)]), title: "")
}
```

And you get n `BarCharView`.

So, you are doing the `ForEach()` at the wrong place.

You could explicitly do:

```
var values: [(String, Double)] = []
for aResult in vm.res {
    let newValue = ("", aResult.new_cases)
    values.append(newValue)
}
BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: values), title: "")
```

With a more high level method: `map()`:

```
BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: vm.res.map{ ("", $0.new_cases)}),  
             title: "")
```